# Rest API does not work after changing Wordpress Theme

Tags: themes, rest-api, api

Rest API works perfectly with default theme twenty sixteen, but when I change the theme the post on site does not appear. Anyone have the exact problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://mywebsite.com/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&per_page=3',            

        success: function (data) {
            var posts_html = '';
            $.each(data, function (index, post) {
              //posts_html += '<a href="' + post.link + '"><h2>' + post.title.rendered + '</h2></a>';
              //posts_html += '<p>' + post.excerpt.rendered + '</p>';
              posts_html += '<div class="blogpost">';
              posts_html += '<div class="post-item">'
              posts_html += '<div class="post-item-image">';
              posts_html += '<a href="' + post.source_url + '"></a>';
              posts_html += '<img src="' + post.images.large + '" alt="'+ post.title.rendered + '"</div>';
              posts_html += '<div class="post-item-header">';
              posts_html += '<span class="date">' + moment(post.date).format("Do MMM YY") + '</span>';
              posts_html += '<span class="user">';
              posts_html += '<a href="' + post.link +'">';
              posts_html += '<img src="https://mywebsite.com/img/p2plogo.png" alt="P2Pbench logo" >P2Pbench</a></span></div>';
              posts_html += '<div class="post-item-body">';
              posts_html += '<a href="' + post.link + '" style="text-decoration: underline;"> '+ post.title.rendered + '</a>';
              posts_html += '<div class="post-short-text"> ' + post.excerpt.rendered + '</div></div></div></div></div>';
            });
            $('#posts').html(posts_html);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
     <div class="blogs-post-list">
    <div id="posts">Loading posts...
   </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does the id "posts" exist on the page?  Did you reset the permalinks?

Comment: "does not work" is not a useful description of a problem. What specifically is not working? Are there errors in the console? What do you see for the request in the Network tab for the request? Are you getting an alert from your `error` function?

Comment: No, I didn't reset the permalinks

Comment: I added the HTML code. I don't get any error. Just loading posts.... are displayed. But when I change the WP theme to tweenty sixteen the post appear from blog to website.

Comment: WordPress uses jQuery.noConflict I think, meaning it doesn't define `$` by default: you'll have to use `jQuery` instead. Could that be it? However I'd be surprised if twentysixteen loaded jQuery as $, and you would see errors in your browser's JavaScript console for this. Can you answer the rest of Jacob's questions: if you open your browser's debug tools and reload the page, then look at the 'console' do you see any errors? If you look at the network tab do you see the request to the /v2/posts endpoint, and did it complete successfully?

Comment: Yup! The problem was identified - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'large' of undefined.... the problem is this line  posts_html += '<img src="' + post.images.large + '" alt="'+ post.title.rendered + '"</div>';   But why?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solved it by adding this code (at the bottom) to the YOUR BLOG THEMES my path : wp-content/themes/MYWPTHEME/function.php

```
    function ws_register_images_field() {
    register_rest_field( 
        'post',
        'images',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'ws_get_images_urls',
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema'          => null,
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'ws_register_images_field' );

function ws_get_images_urls( $object, $field_name, $request ) {
    $medium = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $object->id ), 'medium' );
    $medium_url = $medium['0'];

    $large = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $object->id ), 'large' );
    $large_url = $large['0'];

    return array(
        'medium' => $medium_url,
        'large'  => $large_url,
    );
}
```